# set default Time on empty datetime picker

Tags: kendo-ui

So pretty new to Kendo (Know enough to be truly dangerous) and I'm trying to figure out how to set the default time to not be 12 AM.

I know I can pass in a datetime value, and it will go off of that, but what I'm trying to do it leave the field empty, but then have the first time available be 8 AM.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to limit the available times? Maybe this will help you: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/timepicker/rangeselection

Comment: I don't want to limit the range, i just don't want the default time to be 8 AM instead of midnight.

Comment: So you have to set the time in the open-event, if there is non set, yet: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datetimepicker/events/open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the code below suits your needs. I made a simple demo with global variables to give you a feel for the solution.

What I do in the demo is check whether the change to the value is the first change and whether it's done from the date view. If both are true, the time is set to 8:00.

You can use a similar method to set a default date if the time value is the first one selected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<input id="datetimepicker" />
<script>
    let mode;
    let firstChange = true;

    $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
        open: function(e) {
            mode = e.view;
        },
        change: function(e) {
            if (mode === "date" && firstChange) {
                let currentDate = e.sender.value();

                e.sender.value(new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate(), 8, 0, 0));

                firstChange = false;
            } else {
              firstChange = false;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like that solution.  While not perfect (if they pick the time first its still 12 AM)  but that it 95% of what I was trying to do!

Comment: Are you sure? That's not what I'm seeing when I run the snippet... Once a time is set, whether by selecting the time or from getting the value from the code I wrote, the time persists when a date is selected. What exactly is happening when you do it?

Comment: When I run the code snippet and select the time without a date, it still defaults to 12 AM

Comment: That's very strange, it works fine for me in several browsers I've checked. I don't see how the code above could cause that. The behavior you're describing breaks the defined behavior of the DateTimePicker for picking time. Did you try debugging it? Try commenting out the entire `change` block in the code and see if it starts working properly.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it locally yet, i was just trying it through the stackoverflow snippet option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your requirement but you can set default date time according to your requirement.

```
$("#dtpXYZ).data('kendoDatePicker').value(kendo.toString(new Date($.now()), 'dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm'));
```

Comment: but that would display the current date and time.  I'm looking for the field to remain blank, but have the default time not be 12 AM